# How do I invert the Fn keys on my Asus laptop? (Windows 8)

Tags: windows, windows-8, asus-laptop, fn-key

I have an ASUS laptop with Windows 8 installed. I want to use <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> to control the volume, brightness, etc. all the time (since I don't use these keys).

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you meant by invert? Also please post the model of your machine and the OS you are running. It's better if you do this by editing your question, rather than simply commenting.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your buttons are defaulting to F1-F12, and you want to use the volume, brightness, etc. Unfortunately for ASUS laptops, there's no way to set your keys to do those things by default. The only way to do that is to press FN+Fx.